# Even after placing Client ID and Client Secret, why is Firebase sign-in method showing Client ID and Client Secret Required?

Tags: oauth, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I am creating a react.js web app with third party authentication using Github and firebase SDK.

I registered an OAuth app in Github and got the Client ID and Client Secret and placed them inside the firebase sign-in methods fields for Github, but it is still showing Client ID and Client Secret Required and the save button is disabled.

[image]

Any reasons why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So i fixed it. I closed all the running extensions on the browser and it worked!!!